# How do I change the border color of words matching a selection in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

For example, double clicking on a word selects it, then all matches of that word are also highlighted.

What keys do I change in my theme to change the background, foreground, and/or the border colors for the matching words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no configuration key for the colour of the border around unselected found text in Sublime Text 2: the colour of the *found text* border is the cursor colour. If you want to change it, you must change the cursor colour.

To change the cursor and *found text* border colour, set the value of the key named `caret` in the `.thTheme` file.

In other words, if you want a yellow *found text* border, you must also have a hello cursor. For example:

```
<key>caret</key>
<string>#ffff00</string>
```

This how the it looks with a yellow *found text* border and cursor in the Monokai Bright theme:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `findHighlight` and `inactiveSelection`

```
            <key>selection</key>
            <string>#C5DFE980</string>

            <key>findHighlight</key>
            <string>#ffe792</string>

            <key>inactiveSelection</key>
            <string>#ff7e00</string>
```

Comment: None of those work. `selection` only changes the color of the actual selection. `inactiveSelection` and `findHighlight` seem to change nothing at all.

Comment: `inactiveSelection` changes the colour of selected text when the window is not in focus. `findHighlight` changes the background colour of found text.

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text 3 `highlight` option changes border color of matching elements

```
<key>highlight</key>
<string>#ff00ff</string>
```